# GNOME fractional scaling benefit vs lower resolution

Tags: ubuntu, gnome3, resolution

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on a Dell XPS 13 with FHD display (1920x1080 resolution).
Clearly, this resolution is too much for my eyes with a 13.3" display, so I'm vetting a couple of alternative solutions.

1. Using this resolution (1920x1080) but using the fractional scaling provided by both Wayland and X, and set it at 125%.
2. Using a lower resolution (1600x900) with scaling at 100%.

Honestly, at a glance, I could not see any difference, so, which are the pros and the cons of both the options, both in aesthetical terms and performance terms (e.g. higher consumption, known bugs, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fractional scaling will consume more power, I believe. It can give performance issues.

Using a lower resolution should definitely be noticeably worse.

Another option would be to use GNOME Tweaks and scale the font while on native resolution (1920x1080 here) with 100% scaling.